# Node.js - AWS SNS Only HTTPS EndPoint not receiving any data from AWS, if Used HTTP, working perfectly fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, https, amazon-sns

Issue: I'm not receiving any subscription confirmation token data on **HTTPs** endpoint. I've tested using HTTP and it's receiving all data.

What I've tried already:

1. whole AWS documentation tried [each & every step]
2. finding through google and spent so much time on that, then I came here!
3. I'm using EC2 and instance is public means can hit get/post request from Postman and on browser, so it's not that issue, i'm sure.
4. disabled my anti-malware and still HTTP receiving the request meaning my firewall isn't blocking any AWS sending request mechanism
5. tried on different ports, HTTP works fine, **HTTPS** doesn't!

My primary educated guess is that the culprit is the SSL Certificate, because in aws documentation, they mentioned that if the CA is not recognizable from AWS then they might not send the data. I'm using .PFX file with passphrase.

Comment: Are you able to test HTTPS on your local VM container such as Tomcat?

Comment: @Rizwan I'm using node.js with express server and it's deployed on EC2

Comment: Can you share the network, log from debug window from the browser what you get part of Response Header? Or it is plain Timeout?